# Почему нет реактивности во входном параметре vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть табы и кликая на них должна выходить нужная информация, и со временем она подгружается и пополняется, но этого не происходит из-за того что у меня нету реактивности на входные параметры дочернего компонента

суть такая:

```
data() {
  return {
    api: []
  }
} // это родительский компонент с данными

props: [api]// дочерний компонент
```

Дело в том, что при изменении родительских данных не меняются дочерние

Что делать?(

Comment: Приведите пример HTML кода, а не эту диаграмму

Comment: Всё работает [в соответствии с документацией](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Для организации двунаправленного потока данных можно использовать свойства в комбинации с пользовательскими событиям.